# iphone image library

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, photo-gallery

I need to work on an image library for iphone/ipad devices. I once saw a sample code in which we could arrange multiple images in landscape format with three images on every screen and image in the center was larger and in front. We could easily scroll through it. I am not able to find this sample code on the net now when I need it.:-(

There was another one where images were arranged in like a file in a drawer. If any one could provide me this code, it will again be a great help

Does someone have these sample code?

Thanks
Pankaj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it have been [Coverflow](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary/wiki/Coverflow) in the Tapku library?

Comment: Thanks Jakob this what I wanted but while searching I found another library which does similar task but with different ways. https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Comment: just check this one it is awsome